# the problem about position of “sections” and “references”

Tags: cross-referencing

### CODE

```
\documentclass[cs4size,a4paper,UTF8,twoside]{ctexart}
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents 
%section 
    \section{section1}
    1111111111
    \section{section 2}
    2222222222
    \section{section 3}
    3333333333
    \section{section 4}
    4444444444
%reference
{\zihao{5}
    \renewcommand\refname{{\zihao{4}参考文献 }}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\heiti 参考文献}
    \setlength\lineskip{18pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{thebibliography}{42}  
            \setlength{\itemsep}{-2mm}
            \bibitem{ref1}ref1
            \bibitem{ref2}re2
            \bibitem{ref3}ref3 
        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{flushleft}
}
\end{document}
```

### PROBLEM

I use the `\CTEXsetup[format={\Large\bfseries}]{section}` to set "section" left aligned
but the “references” can not on the center
[image]
 I have looked up some information on the Internet, but it doesn't seem to work.I don't know what to do now。

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Which version of `ctex` package are you using?

Comment: @egreg You know, latex's "section" is in the middle of the page, and I chose to put the "section" to the left.
I can use the "\CTEXsetup[format={\Large\bfseries}]{section}" command to place "section" on the left side of the page.But in this case, my "" references" will also go to the left.I want the section to go to the left."The references to the right

Comment: Could you please add a MWE which looks like the image snap posted. ? 
Also, in your question ``\begin{flushleft}`` environment is not closed!!

Comment: I have return my question.Forgive my poor english@Tavnvir